# How can i start the constructor from my class?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

i am having this problem and it is driving me crazy, i have this class

```
    package Test;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Firefox {

    String keyFirefox = "webdriver.gecko.driver";
    String valueFirefox = "...path/geckodriver.exe";

    public Firefox(){
        System.setProperty(keyFirefox, valueFirefox);
    }

    WebDriver Firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

and in my main class i instantiate the the previous class and can access to the properties without any problem

```
package Test;


public class EntryPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Firefox firefoxBrowser = new Firefox();
        firefoxBrowser.Firefox.get("https://www.amazon.com.mx/");


    }

}
```

But when it compiles it return me an error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases**

Thank you!

Comment: The `Firefox` variable is created before the constructor is called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create the driver after setting the properties, try

```
public class Firefox {

    static final String FIREFOX_DRIVER = "webdriver.gecko.driver";
    static final String FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH = "...path/geckodriver.exe";

    WebDriver driver;

    public Firefox(){
        System.setProperty(FIREFOX_DRIVER, FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }


}
```